TypeScript: variable is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
In one of my Angular projects, I have one interface in userinterface.ts
export interface Done {
    wordlen: number;
    word: string;    
};

which I am using to populate a array
donearr: Done[] = [];
let fill:Done  = {  wordlen: 4, word: "word" }
this.donearr.push(fill)    

It is working till here. But when I take the last object from array for some processing it throws error.
let v_last = this.donearr.pop()        
console.log(v_last) // this displays the array content
console.log(v_last.wordlen) // this gives error. 
                            // 'v_last' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
                            // let v_last: Done | undefined

I have tried let v_last: Done = this.donearr.pop()   but that also gives error.
Type 'Done | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Done'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Done'.ts(2322)

Where I am taking it wrong ?

TypeScript is warning you that v_last could be undefined, and accessing a property on undefined will cause a runtime error

Since the method Array.pop() possibly returns undefined. Typescript will make you check it out. In this case you are sure Array.pop() will return a non-undefined value, so instead of writing let v_last = this.donearr.pop() you can write let v_last = this.donearr.pop()! (notice the "!"-mark). This means that you are sure this code will always return something.
Make sure to check out:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks

let v_last = this.donearr.pop(); // here type will be inferred, no need to specify    
console.log(v_last);
console.log(v_last?.wordlen); // and use optional changing to avoid runtime and ts errors


TypeScript says the pop might return undefined so we need can use the typesafe check ?. to work even if the value is undefined.
let v_last: Done | undefined = this.donearr.pop();        
console.log(v_last);
console.log(v_last?.wordlen);

You can also just add a if condition to prevent the undefined value.
 let v_last: Done | undefined = this.donearr.pop();        
 if (v_last) {
     console.log(v_last);
     console.log(v_last.wordlen);
 }

